# Binary variables for bin packing with R?

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, bin-packing

I'm trying to build an optimization model in R for a bin packing problem. There usually is a binary variable that is either 1 if a figure is chosen for the final result or 0 otherwise. That variable is useful because a away to null some of the constraints is required. For example, when the solver is trying to check if the rectangular figure can fit in the box ( given a fixed height and width for the box and a height and width for each figure) one of the constraints usually is:

Xc >= ((width)/2)*bc

Xc is the horizontal component for the allocation of the figure (it's a a 2 dimensional problem treated in a Cartesian plane)

Bc = binary variable.

Thia basically means that the x component for the center needs to be greater than the numeric value of ithe figures's width divided by 2. This is the constraint to make sure the item doesn't cross the left limit of the box. If the figure is chosen, the binary variable is 1 and this constraint is checked, otherwise, the zero is going to null the right part and the x component of the figure that is not being considered can be anything else.

I have no idea how can I set these binary variables. Each figure needs one of these and the Objective Function basically is to maximize the sum of this variables.

Should I search for dummy variables in this case or something else?

Comment: If I read this correctly, you can precalculate if a "figure" can fit into a box. No need to use binary variables for this. Then you can set `X(f,b)=0` if it does not fit. Or even better only generate variables `X(f,b)` for valid pairs `(f,b)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lpsolve` package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolve/lpSolve.pdf. In the primitive `lp()` in this package have provision for defining integer variables through int.vec

> **int.vec**: Numeric vector giving the indices of variables that are required to be integer.
>   The length of this vector will therefore be the number of integer variables

There are more such MIP packages (check [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html); currently cplexAPI, glpkAPI, lpSolve, lpSolveAPI, Rcplex, Rglpk, rLindo, Rmosek, Rsymphony) with each having custom provision for integer decision variable.